# detect and Sum Year,Months and Days

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

i have my code below which works fine before,to display as years,months and days.so as the one below i sum it up to display as days only that i do some conversions.i face some minor problems in my code. my year display 330 instead of 365.if i type in 1 year it should display 365, 1 month should be 30..but if 34 days it should be display as 34, instead it display as 60days.anyone can figure it out how come i got this error im my code below.this my code in my report properties in ssrs 2008

```
Public Function ILength(length  As Integer ) As String

           dim year As Integer=0
           dim month As Integer=0
           dim day  As Integer=0
           dim sum  as integer


if(length =0)
Return String.Empty
end if

if length >= 366 then
year=cstr(Math.Floor (length/ 365.25)) 
length =(length  Mod 365.25)
length =(year * 365)
year =cstr(length)

end if

if length>31 Andalso length<366  then

month=cstr (Math.Floor(length/30.4375))
length=(length  Mod 30.4375)
length=(month * 30)
month=cstr(length)

end if

if length<31 Then
day =cstr(length) 
end if

if length = 0 then
Return String.Empty
end if

sum= ((year)+(month)+(day))

return(sum)

End Function
```

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what input and output you are expecting. Please clarify that.

Comment: I would seriously consider using the .Net Date (DateTime) object to do this type of work. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Meta-Knigh..i was expecting like if i enter 1 year,2 months and 3 days i was expecting to output 428days since 1 year is equal to 365, months 30days and days 3, so add it up should display 428 as in days

Comment: @BPete..i have a parameters(ssrs 2008) to choose the date from start and end date that a person falls into..so that one works fine..

Answer (score 0):

As B Pete has mentioned you are reinventing the wheel.  The Visual Basic Runtime library functions are all available and have been tested and used by thousands of developers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c157t28f.aspx

E.g. DateDiff

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t83eh0x7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems with your logic.

1. Firstly you shouldn't be converting anything to string (CStr) at all. The only reason you might need to do that in SSRS is to display a tool-tip or some other string-only field. You certainly shouldn't be trying to do that prior to summing them, although that doesn't work the way you are expecting anyway.
2. Secondly the parameter that your function takes is 'length' which this code assumes is the number of days. You are then returning the number of days. The function doesn't seem to have a purpose other than to split up a length of days into set values of year(365.25) and month (30) and then recombining to add up this standardised year and month lengths. Except that you seem to have incorporated leap years in a crude fashion. Who is to say that length of 366 days is a year? It could be a leap year or it could be 1 year and 1 day.
3. The variables you have declared are all integers but you are using floats or decimals in your math.
4. You are getting the values for year & month but then overwriting them with other values in unecessary steps.

Assuming you have a good reason for doing all this (please share!) and can't use something simple like: `=datediff(d,fields!FirstDate.Value,fields!SecondDate.value)`

then I can show you where this function is going wrong.

In this part:

```
if length >= 366 then
year=cstr(Math.Floor (length/ 365.25)) 
length =(length  Mod 365.25)
length =(year * 365)
year =cstr(length)
```

Take an input value of 367. the second line will give you year=1. The third line will give you length=0. Yes, zero. You've declared everything as integers, and integers will implicity truncate any mantissa (the bit after the decimal point). You want to declare these as a floating point or better, an exact numeric. The fourth line overwrites your length value with Year(1) * 365 = 365. The fifth line then converts 365 to a string and assigns it to year, except year is an integer so it is implicitly cast back to an integer. If your variables were declared as the right type, you only need these 3 lines, but again the 366 days thing is very agricultural. It handles edge cases poorly.

```
if length >= 366 then
year=cstr(Math.Floor (length/ 365.25)) 
length =(length  Mod 365.25)
```

The next part:

```
if length>31 Andalso length<366  then
```

This is also unecessary. You've already ensured in the first part of the code that the length is now less than 365 (and if the variables were the right datatype then length would be less than 365.25)

This is enough:

```
if length>31 then
```

You've done the same thing in this next part, the first two lines are enough, again assuming your datatypes are fixed.

```
month=cstr (Math.Floor(length/30.4375))
length=(length  Mod 30.4375)
length=(month * 30)
month=cstr(length)
```

In this next part, it works (apart from the Cstr) but is uncomfortable. You should check for length = 0 before you test if length < 31.

```
if length<31 Then
day =cstr(length) 
end if

if length = 0 then
Return String.Empty
end if
```

You said in the comments two conflicting statements. First that you have inputs like year / month days and second that you have start and end date parameters. If the second is true and you have start / end dates then throw away this code and use datediff. The inbuilt functions already consider leap years and the actual lenghths of months, no need for you to use crude averages.

It seems like you've used custom code for the sake of it, a complex solution to a non-existant problem.

Comment: i enter year months and days in my textbox...so before i display in days it was display as 1 years 2 months and 6 days, which was running fine.but now i want to convert into days and add all.as for your comment @Davos..Now i enter months and days it display the right output  when i run my ssrs 2008.eg 5days in a text box =5 days and enter 2 months in my text box,run the ssrs i got 60days.i don't care if its leap year but as requirement says it should be display as 30 day.the only problem is that i cant display the year correctly as it display 330 instead of 365 for 1 year...thanks

Comment: Can you explain how you go from year / month / day text entry to the single "length" parameter in this function? I think you would be better not to have text entries too, but rather set the parameters as numeric. What if someone typed in "One"? It would break, and give an obscure error.